# Чем различаются var и object? (C#)

Tags: c#

Почему после объявления переменной choice типа var он позволяет входить в цикл switch? Разве var не должен присваивать конкретный тип результата выполнения условной операции переменной choice (integer или object)? Тем самым один из case'ов не сможет обработать шаблон типа.  Почему choice всё равно обозначается как object в VS?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
        object langChoice = Console.ReadLine();
        var choice = int.TryParse(langChoice.ToString(), out int num) ? num : langChoice;
        switch (choice)
        {
            case int i when i == 2:
            case string s when s.Equals("VB", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase):
                Console.WriteLine("Visual Basic - amazing");
                break;

            case int i when i == 1:
            case string s when s.Equals("C#", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase):
                Console.WriteLine("C# - cool!");
                break;

            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Well.. good luck!");
                break;
        }
```

Comment: выражение `int.TryParse(langChoice.ToString(), out int num) ? num : langChoice;` возвращает результат типа `object`.

Comment: @Grundy: Допустим, что я ввожу в консоль 123 -> langChoice = "123" и является object. Затем мы попадаем в условную операцию, где парсим "123" (string) в 123 (int) -> var choice = num, т.е choice становится int. Если же не получается спарсить в int, то var choice = langChoice, т.е choice становится object. Почему же выражение в любом случае возвращает результат типа object?

Comment: Из-за таких скрытых от глаз штук, я не люблю `var`.

Comment: @aepot, причем тут var вообще?

Comment: @Grundy при том что черт его знает, какого типа там `choice`, пока инспектором не наведешься. Для опытного разраба мелочь, а для новичка - вот такие вот вопросы.

Comment: @aepot в случае когда "черт его знает что это выражение возвращает" - это вина выражения, а не `var`. Код надо писать так, чтобы было понятно, что он делает, без плясок вокруг типов переменных.

Comment: @tym32167 полностью согласен. Я сам иногда `var` использую, но в основном, чтобы скрыть всякие длинные `IEnumerable<MyCoolDerivedType<InputType, ResultType>>` или при работе с анонимными типами. А вот разрабов, которые используют `var` вместо `int` я искренне не понимаю. :)

Comment: @aepot хз, я и так и так пользуюсь, обычно стараюсь быть консистентным, если var так var, чтобы не думать "а вот тут надо тип, а вот тут не надо".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как уже упомянул Grundy var выводится в object.
У вас в правой части тернарный оператор, то есть получается, что если методу удастся получить целое число (int) из langChoice, то он вернет значение переменной num типа int, иначе вернет langChoice, который является объектом. Он вывел тип на основе того факта, что он не знает, что будет в локальной переменной langChoice, поэтому он не знает, может ли он привести к типу int, а локальную переменную типа int можно легко привести к object(упаковать).

Comment: факт упаковки решил дилемму, спасибо!

Comment: в первую очередь стоило бы упомянуть, что `var` - это не тип сам по себе, а плейсхолдер для типа, который подставляет на его место компилятор при сборке.